# Zeroes of exact differential forms on compact manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $M$ be a $n$ dimensional compact differentiable manifold. I would like to show that any exact differential form of degree $n$ vanishes at at least one point.

I think it is a generalization of the following fact : if $f$ is a diffferentiable function on $M$ then it either has a maximum or is constant so it's differential vanishes at at least one point.

**edit** I'm looking for a direct answer if possible maybe in the spirit of the above remark.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say $\alpha$ is your exact degree $n$ form. Since it is exact, there exists $\tau$ such that $\alpha = d\tau$. Suppose now $M$ is orientable. Then, since it's also compact, we can do integration, in which case Stokes' Theorem tells us that $\int_M\alpha = \int_Md\tau = \int_{\partial M}\tau = 0$ since the boundary $\partial M$ of $M$ is empty. From this we know $\alpha$ must vanish at some point because otherwise it would be a volume form on $M$ which can't have $0$ volume.

If instead $M$ is non-orientable, take its orientation double cover $\pi: \widetilde{M} \rightarrow M$ (which you can check will still be compact) and pullback $\alpha$. Then $\pi^*\alpha$ will still be exact since $\alpha$ is, so we can repeat the argument upstairs to find that $\pi^*\alpha$ vanishes at some point $p \in \widetilde{M}$. Then you can find that $\alpha$ vanishes at $\pi(p) \in M$.

**Edit**: as pointed out by Georges in the comments, if we start out assuming (for sake of contradiction) that $\alpha$ is non-vanishing, then it would be an orientation form for $M$ and the argument in the first paragraph then suffices for a shorter proof.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! My goal was kind of not to have to talk about orientations (I asked myself this question while trying to learn about orientations) and just give a direct proof, so i am going to keep the question open just a little longer to see if maybe someone comes up with a more "direct proof".

Comment: Dear John, if $\alpha$ did not vanish it would give an orientation for $M$, which leads to a contradiction as you showed  in the first part of your proof . So actually $\alpha$ **does** vanish: end of proof. The second section starting with  "If instead..." can be deleted.

Comment: Maybe a way to get the answer I "want" would be to understand why a volume form (which for me is by definition of form which doesn't vanish at any point) can't give volume $0$ to $M$ ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: agreed! Since your modification would require the assumption of $\alpha$ non-vanishing from the outset, I added your note as an edit rather than change the answer too much, since people had already voted.

Comment: Just for completeness: Your proof assumes that $M$ is connected (since vanishing of $\int \alpha$ may not imply that $\alpha$ vanishes at some point otherwise). But you can as well run the argument for each connected component.

Comment: Dear john, adding an edit is quite all right. Anyway, yours is a fine answer: bravo!

Comment: Why the boundary $\partial M$ is empty ? A compact manifold has a boundary. Is it not ? Had it been a closed manifold, I understand. Can you please clarify ?