# vanishing of differential form on connected compact manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $M$ be a $n$ dimensional compact connected manifold. Let $\alpha$ be a differential form of degree $n$ such that 
$$
\int_{M} \alpha = 0
$$
then I would like to show that $\alpha$ vanishes at at least one point of $M$.

One could just say that a volume form can't give $0$ volume to the manifold but that's precisely the result whose proof I would like to understand.

I'm looking for an "elementary" answer if possible which doesn't use orientations (or if so explains the result used).

This question is linked to my previous question : [Zeroes of exact differential forms on compact manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749784/zeroes-of-exact-differential-forms-on-compact-manifold)
indeed I am asking this question to understand the answer of the previous one.

Comment: It has to be a scalar multiple of the volume form. Look at that multiple. If it never zero, it's either always positive or always negative...

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your comment but that is precisely the kind of answers that i am trying to avoid. I want to understand this without assuming anything about volume forms and such.

Comment: How are you defining the integral of a differential form if you haven't introduced orientations?

Comment: It's not that I haven't introduced orientations it's just that I am looking for the kind of answers that would be more "hands on" but maybe it doesn't exists. Again what i'm really interested in is a "simple" answer as to why an exact $n$-form vanishes at a point.

Comment: An “elementary” proof of an existence statement can be kind of hard.  Even in the case $n=1$: If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, and $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = 0$, then there exists a point $c$ in $[a,b]$ such that $f(c) = 0$.  Is there an elementary proof of that?

Comment: well if the function is strictly positive (resp negative) then the integral is strictly postive (resp negative) so f has to take both postive and negative values so there is a point where it is 0 right ? But of course i'm not saying that it should be that elementary. Anyway I feel like it wasn't such a good question in the end, sorry about that :) What really interests me is my previous question for which I really hope to find an "hands on" answer which maybe doesn't use integration.